# How to increase the Power Query timeout beyond 5 minutes?

Tags: powerbi, timeout, azure-data-explorer

Using Power Query to query Kusto and the query times out after 5 minutes even though I've set the timeout to 21 minutes, like this:

`[Timeout = #duration(0,0,21,0), ClientRequestProperties = [#"query_language" = "csl"]])`

The query in question typically takes about 7-10 minutes when run directly in Kusto.

A similar question asked here had an answer that suggested going to "Data source settings" and clicking on "Change Source..." but that button is grayed for me. Besides, the above, query-specific setting should override a global setting, right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using the `AzureDataExplorer.Contents()` or `Kusto.Contents()` methods, there was a regression in the Timeout implementations of the connector. This was fixed on Jun 7 2021, and should be included in version 3.0.52 of the connector (should already be publicly available - make sure you have the latest version of the PBI Desktop).

If you're still facing an issue, contact me directly at itsagui(at)microsoft.com